# Can not generate source code with SBT 0.11 from "Full Configuration"

Tags: scala, code-generation, sbt

Based on sbt 0.11.0 documentation available (["Common Tasks" wiki page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Common-Tasks) and others) and after seeing how this is done in [Scalaz SBT build](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/9447035544938f44f21b26c822edd9d9d7357838/project/ScalazBuild.scala) and in [Scalate SBT build](https://gist.github.com/1017782) I can't figure out why my simple example does not work:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val project = Project(
    id = "root", 
    base = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      (sourceGenerators in Compile) <+= (sourceManaged in Compile) map { dir =>
        val file = dir / "bla.scala"
        IO.write(file, """object Bla extends App { println("bla!") }""")
        Seq(file)
      }
    )
  )

}
```

Putting that on project/build.scala of an empty project and running "sbt compile" generates/compiles nothing and "sbt run" complains that it can not find any main class.

Now, if I put the setting in the "quick configuration" build.sbt as follows instead of the full configuration as above, it just works.

```
(sourceGenerators in Compile) <+= (sourceManaged in Compile) map { dir =>
    val file = dir / "bla.scala"
    IO.write(file, """object Bla extends App { println("bla!") }""")
    Seq(file)
}
```

Obviously, needing to create a build.sbt file in a "full configuration"-only project is far from desirable, at least for me.

So, why this setting is not working in the full configuration?

Comment: I copied and pasted the above into project/Build.scala, ran 'sbt run', and it printed bla! as expected.  Perhaps check that the filename is right and that the definition is getting loaded by throwing in a println in the object or by changing a setting and verifying it takes effect.

Comment: Does `project/build.scala` fail where `project/Build.scala` succeeds?

Comment: this guy well deserves a massive down-vote for keeping the answer not accepted for a year. let me be the first one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy paste your code in file `project/Build.scala` and run it with `sbt run` and that works.

Are your sure that your `Build.scala` is correctly located (must be in `project` directory) ?